# Shorten execution time and file size of SVG graph generation

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot

My program generated a dot file `a.dot`, then I use `dot -Tsvg a.dot > a.svg` 
But there two problems about using the transformation script:

- Is there way to **shorten the execution time** of the command? Currently, the verbose mode prints out:

> ```
> dot - graphviz version 2.30.1 (20130218.1601)
> libdir = "/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.30.1/lib/graphviz"
> Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_quartz.6.dylib
> Using textlayout: textlayout:quartz
> Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.6.dylib
> Using render: svg:core
> Using device: svg:svg:core
> Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.6.dylib
> Using layout: dot:dot_layout
> The plugin configuration file:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.30.1/lib/graphviz/config6
>       was successfully loaded.
>     render    :  dot fig map pic pov ps quartz svg tk vml xdot
>     layout    :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
>     textlayout    :  textlayout
>     device    :  bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps exr fig gif gv imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg pct pdf pic pict plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vml vmlz
> xdot
>     loadimage :  (lib) bmp eps gif jpe jpeg jpg pdf png ps svg
>
> fontname: unable to resolve "Times-Roman"
>
> network simplex:  1096 nodes 1155 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=1
>
> network simplex: 1096 nodes 1155 edges 1 iter 0.00 sec
>
> Maxrank = 416, minrank = 0
>
> mincross: pass 0 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 0 best_cross 0
>
> mincross BST: 0 crossings, 0.10 secs.
>
> network simplex:  48344 nodes 72433 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2
>
> network simplex: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000
>
> network simplex: 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000
>
> network simplex: 2100 2200 2300 2400 2500 2600 2700 2800 2900 3000
>
> network simplex: 3100 3200 3300 3400 3500 3600 3700 3800 3900 4000
>
> network simplex: 4100 4200 4300 4400 4500 4600 4700 4800 4900 5000
>
> network simplex: 5100 5200 5300 5400 5500 5600 5700 5800 5900 6000
>
> network simplex: 6100 6200 6300 6400 6500 6600 6700 6800 6900 7000
>
> network simplex: 7100 7200 7300 7400 7500 7600 7700 7800 7900 8000
>
> network simplex: 8100 8200 8300 8400 8500 8600 8700 8800 8900 9000
>
> network simplex: 9100 9200 9300 9400 9500 9600 9700 9800 9900 10000
>
> network simplex: 10100 10200 10300 10400 10500 10600 10700 10800 10900 11000
>
> network simplex: 11100 11200 11300 11400 11500 11600 11700 11800 11900 12000
>
> network simplex: 12100 12200 12300 12400 12500 12600 12700 12800 12900 13000
>
> network simplex: 13100 13200 13300 13400 13500 13600 13700 13800 13900 14000
> ```

It just keeps on printing out the `network simplex:...`

- Is there way to **reduce the size** of generated svg file?
  Because  client needs to load the svg into browser, it is better to be small...

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have too many nodes/edges. It will be a big file.

Comment: @JamesBlack Is there better way to do this?

Comment: This is difficult to optimize without seeing the actual input. However, if you do have 48000 nodes, there's probably little you can do.

Comment: @marapet hmmm..it seems infeasible to list the file content here, it is too long...

Comment: Create a very large PNG perhaps, or use the canvas tag, and just send the minimum information in a json file.